# ng-change increment and decrement value in ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to LearnKode - A code learning platform</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="changeExample">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 well">
                    Are you developer  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isTrue" ng-change="count=count+1" />
                   Count: {{count}}
                    <pre>{{isTrue}}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module("changeExample", []);
        app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.isTrue = true;
        }]);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In this code when check the checkbox the count will be incremented. Here how to i check if checkbox is ticked, then only incremented, otherwise if untick, it will decremented. Please anyone help.

Comment: Try `ng-change="isTrue ? (count=count+1) :(count=count-1)`

Comment: Then what was your this requirement for? "I have multiple check boxes in ng-repeat loop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Welcome to LearnKode - A code learning platform</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="changeExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3 well">
        Are you developer
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isTrue" ng-change="isTrue ? (count=count+1) :(count=count-1) " />Count: {{count}}
        <pre>{{isTrue}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("changeExample", []);
    app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.isTrue = false;
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

try changing ng-change .

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to LearnKode - A code learning platform</title>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="changeExample">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-3 well" ng-repeat="Option in OptionList">
                    Are you {{Option.choice}}  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Option.value" ng-change="UpdateCount(Option)" />
                   Count: {{Option.count}}
                    <pre>{{Option.isTrue}}</pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module("changeExample", []);
        app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.isTrue = false;
   $scope.count = 0;
   $scope.OptionList = [{
    choice: "Developer",
    value: false,
    count: 0
   },{
    choice: "Tester",
    value: false,
    count: 0
   },{
    choice: "Lead",
    value: false,
    count: 0
   },{
    choice: "Architect",
    value: false,
    count: 0
   }
  ];
  $scope.UpdateCount = function(Option){
   if(Option.value){
     Option.count = Option.count + 1;
   }
   else {
    Option.count = Option.count - 1;
   }
  }
        }]);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have multiple check boxes in ng-repeat loop.

Comment: You can use model value as an ng-repeat property and pass that property to the same function. Writing inline function definition is not a good coding procedure.